# Problems Installing ssd1306 library on rpI pICO

Tags: i2c, pi-pico

Using Manage Packages in Thonny I had successfully installed the ssd1306 library onto my Pico and had the OLED working successfully.  When showing a student how to download the library I got the following error:

Warning: micropython.org SSL certificate is not validated

micropip returned with error code 1

Most of my students also got the same error.  Any suggestions on how to get around the error and install the ssd1306 library?

Thanks in advance,
Fred

Comment: (1) Ah, the problem might be you insisted to install the version from micropython.org. (2) What I did was the following: (b) ***Search PyPI***, (c) Install the micropython version there. No SSL cert is asked.  (3) I am using Windows 10 Thonny. (4) You might like to uninstall your SSD1306, and see if you can reinstall the PyPI version again.